# When i want to delete a collectionviewcell inside a tableviewcell through a gesturerecognizer it only works in the first tableviewcell

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, tableview, collectionview

here is my code to delete the cell inside the "didSelectItemAt" function:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let longPressGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(removeEvent(gesture:)))

        collectionView.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGesture)
    }

    func removeEvent(gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        if gesture.state == .began {
            let touchPoint = gesture.location(in: self.collectionView)
            if let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: touchPoint) {
                print(indexPath)

                let event = controller.object(at: indexPath as IndexPath)
                context.delete(event)
                collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
```

And now the problem is that the deleteing works with a longpress, but it somehow only works in the first TableViewCell and not in the following ones (so it only works in the first collectionview in the first tableviewcell)

i would really appreciate help